# (QTP / UFT) How to change an Insight image during execution?

Tags: automated-testing, qtp

Is it possible to change an Insight image during the execution of a test?

That way, I can have a single object in my object repository, for example "AbstractInsightObj"

I am looking to do something like what I have described below.

Pseudocode:

```
AbstractInsightObj.Click  'Clicks object A
AbstractInsightObj.ChangeImage("C:/pictureOfImageB.jpg")
AbstractInsightObj.Click  'Clicks object B
```

I am aware I can create two separate Insight Objects in the repository, but for my use case, it would be simpler if I could just reuse one repository object.

Does anyone have any insight? (No pun intended.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insight objects can contain the image either internally (when created during record or learn) or by supplying an image (this is probably what you're looking for).

When supplying an image you need to put in in the test object's **ImgSrc** property, this can done either by using [descriptive programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2478005/3848) thus:

```
InsightObject("ImgSrc:=C:\pictureOfImageA.jpg").Click
InsightObject("ImgSrc:=C:\pictureOfImageB.jpg").Click
```

Or by using [`SetTOProperty`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8699178/3848).

```
AbstractInsightObj.Click
AbstractInsightObj.SetTOProperty "ImgSrc", "C:\pictureOfImageB.jpg"
AbstractInsightObj.Click
```

Comment: thank you greatly, I wasn't aware of the ImgSrc property.

Comment: This solution is not working in UFT 12.54

Comment: @Ritwik what isn't working?